# Linux server list users who can login

Tags: python, linux, bash

I would like either a one-liner shell command or a short Bash/Python script that will list all the users on a Linux server that can login to that machine. So users like www-data and mail would be excluded of course, but `root` would be part of the list.

This code, for example, works. I [found it here](https://gist.github.com/1989361). But I'm looking for something simpler cleaner.

```
awk -F: '$2 != "*" && $2 !~ /^!/ { print $1, " can log in" }' /etc/shadow
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I updated the question with some code that works.

Comment: youre pretty much already there, just read the min-user-id value from your sshd config and use it to filter the entries in /etc/passwd|shadow

Comment: @lynks thanks for the sshd tip. I checked but didn't find min-user-id value in my sshd config. But I don't think I'm gonna take the script to that depth. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 server.

Comment: yep I was thinking of something else, ignore me :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this oneliner to list all users that have a password set in /etc/shadow, one per line:

```
getent shadow | egrep '^[^:]*:[*!]:' -v | cut -f1 -d:
```

This only works for local users and not when using an LDAP database or other methods.

If you are using LDAP and you want to list all users in the directory you can try:

```
getent passwd | cut -f1 -d:
```

Although, this will list all users, including 'non-user' accounts, such as `www-data`

Answer (score 1):

I found the Bash script at *[Find Linux users that can log in with password](https://gist.github.com/1989361)*.

**Bash version:**

```
awk -F: '$2 != "*" && $2 !~ /^!/ { print $1, " can log in" }' /etc/shadow
```

**Python version:**

```
users = [i.split(':') for i in open('/etc/shadow').readlines()]
print '\n'.join([i[0] for i in users if i[1] not in ('!', '*')])
```